# How to convert from string to IStream

Tags: c++, wstring

I don't know if this is even possible but I am receiving a value of type `std::string` which contains a string (e.g. `"Hello World"`) and I need to pass it to a variable of type `IStream`.

I haven't found any solution in SO so I am wondering how to do it.

EDIT:

I have a function like this that is called and returns a string.

```
foo1(std::string& testOne) (){
     testOne = "This is my test";
}
```

At the same time, I have another function that does some other operations but the signature requires to use a `IStream` value.

```
foo2(IStream *value)
{
    // Do something here
}
```

The idea is that I want to get the string from `foo1`, convert it to an `IStream` so I can pass it to the function `foo2`.

Comment: Changing my question from wstring to simply string :)

Comment: Make a `std::stringstream` using your string. I think that solves your issue.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand what are you trying to do. What do you mean by "pass `string` to `istream`"? `istream` is input stream - you read data from it (`std::cin` is one example of `std::istream`). For outputting data there is `std::ostream` (like `std::cout`). Can you post some pseudocode illustating what you're trying to do?

Comment: Is `IStream` a COM interface? If so please link to it's documentation.

Comment: Please write valid C++ code and explain any non-`std` types.

Comment: the tag `istream` is for `std::istream`, which seems to be unrelated to the question. removed the tag.

Comment: ...if you actually meant `std::istream` please clarify, `IStream` is not part of the standard library

Comment: It is not std::istream

Comment: You may be looking for [`SHCreateMemStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream), as in `IStream* pStr = SHCreateMemStream(myStr.data(), myStr.size());` (may require some casts).